# PHP Builtin-Server (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu-12.04

I'm working on a Ubuntu 12.04 with `php5-cli` installed.

I am trying to get the builtin-server to work with: `php5 -S localhost:8080`

But it seems that the builtin-server is not implemented or otherwise unavailable.

Is there any way to make this work? Without Apache and other approaches, if possible.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: No errors, just the usage instructions.

Comment: Okay, but i guess the answer from datasage explains it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a guide from https://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-latest-php-in-supported-ubuntu-versions-like-5-4-x-in-ubuntu-1

You could use a ppa to stay up-to-date with php. I use :

[https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5 [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5)

It's now on 5.4. If you want use this ppa do this:

[ppa:ondrej/php5 [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you don't have add-apt-repository binary do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Precautions:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out

Comment: better answer - for your reputation score ;)

Answer (score 1):

The built in server requires php 5.4 or newer. You should be able to use a PPA to get php 5.4 installed on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot the version. In 12.10 the PPA is updated.

Comment: For all searchers: Use repo `ppa:ondrej/php5` for latest releases.